# Can I use quotation marks this way?

Tags: quotation-marks

1. Being special is being better, greater, or otherwise different from what is usual.
2. 'Special' is 'better, greater, or otherwise different from what is usual.'

Are quotations marks used correctly at  sentence 2?

Comment: 2 is only correct if you are quoting an entry from, say, a dictionary. If you *are* then that should have been mentioned, For example, 'Special' is *defined* as 'better, greater....'

Comment: The use of quotation marks would indicate a reference - that is after all what a quote is. Hence one would tend to conclude that it is a definition.